# Spring-Security with two authentication managers

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">



    <http security="none" pattern="/resources/**"/>
    <http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true" pattern="/rest/sales/**" authentication-manager-ref="salesAuth" disable-url-rewriting="true">
          <intercept-url pattern="/rest/sales/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_SALESMANAGER')"/>
         <form-login login-page="/rest/checkSales/salesLogin" 
            default-target-url="/rest/sales/getSalesManagerHome" 
            authentication-failure-url="/rest/checkSales/adminLogin?error" 
            username-parameter="emailId"
            password-parameter="password" 
            login-processing-url="/auth/ogin_check" 
            always-use-default-target="true" 
            />
        <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/rest/check/adminlogout" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
        <csrf />
    </http>

    <!-- enable use-expressions -->
     <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true" >
        <headers>
            <cache-control />
        </headers>
        <intercept-url pattern="/rest/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')" />
        <intercept-url pattern="/rest/sales/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_SALESMANAGER')" />
        <form-login login-page="/rest/check/adminLogin" 
            default-target-url="/rest/admin/adminDashBoard" 
            authentication-failure-url="/rest/check/adminLogin?error" 
            username-parameter="emailId"
            password-parameter="password" 
            login-processing-url="/auth/login_check" 
            always-use-default-target="true" 
            />
        <logout invalidate-session="true" logout-success-url="/rest/check/adminlogout" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" />
        <csrf />
    </http> 

    <!-- Select users and user_roles from database -->
    <authentication-manager erase-credentials="true">
        <authentication-provider >
            <password-encoder ref="encoder" />
            <jdbc-user-service  data-source-ref="dataSource"
                users-by-username-query="select email_id,password, organization_staff_id  from organization_staff where email_id=?"
                authorities-by-username-query="select email_id, staff_type from organization_staff where email_id=?" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <authentication-manager erase-credentials="true"  alias="salesAuth">
        <authentication-provider >
            <password-encoder ref="encoder" />
            <jdbc-user-service  data-source-ref="dataSource"
                users-by-username-query="select email_id,password, organization_staff_id  from organization_staff where email_id=?"
                authorities-by-username-query="select email_id, staff_type from organization_staff where email_id=?" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
    <beans:bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder">
        <beans:constructor-arg name="strength" value="10" />
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

The problem is with second authentication-manager is overriding anthor authentication manager, i.e. always second authentication manager get executing. Here I am using two custom login pages for two different modules in my project, or tell me how to apply Spring Security for two custom login pages in one project.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give your <authentication-manager> an id attribute not an alias, otherwise the second declaration overrides the first. And then I think you should remove the *authentication-manager-ref* attribute.

This has been asked on the old spring [forum](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/security/114612-multiple-authentication-managers-defined-but-only-the-last-one-is-applied) and answered by Luke Taylor (anyone who read Spring security source code will have seen his name a lot) [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/2163)

Comment: how i can specify which <http> refers to which <authentication-manager>,

Comment: Did you read the form thread I liked to, from what I understand you they made it work just be adding the id (and maybe removing the _authentication-manager-ref_). In addition It strikes me as odd that you are using XML configuration for Spring security. Your xsd says you are using Spring 4, is there any reason you don't configure security in code (by extending ```WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter```)